# DC motor speed control without changing the voltage

Tags: motor-controller

My truck's (2013 F150) blower motor lets you control its speed using a dial on the dash. I assumed the dash dial change the resistance of the circuit the blower motor was on, but when I took voltage measurements at the motor they always showed the same number (11 volts) regardless of the dial position.

[image: Slow Speed Dial]

[image: Fast Speed Dial]

Here is a picture of my setup when measuring the voltage:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The motor and circuit are DC. How is it possible for the dash knob to change the amount of current put through the motor without the voltage measurements changing?

The knob works. When changing to a slower position the motor only has 2 amperes passing through it, vs 8 amperes at full power. I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: Does the motor run when measuring the voltage? If not, then your mistake is putting the meter in series with the motor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are measuring it wrong.

To measure voltage, you put the meter in parallel with the load:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fq49ME.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your photos show that you have put the voltmeter in series with the load:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLdNCZ.png)</sup>

That set up is correct for measuring current, but not for measuring voltage.

1. Measure current through the device (ammeter in series with the device.)
2. Measure voltage across the device (voltmeter in parallel with the device.)

Answer (score 3):

Measuring voltage across 2013 F150 blower motor.

[image]

It will be the battery voltage at '4' and progressively reduce down to '1'.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely down to the duty cycle.  By varying the duty cycle (i.e. on-off-on-off periods) of the feed to the motor you can adjust the power delivered, thus changing the blower speed. The multimeter is just showing you the voltage, but not it's cycle characteristics.  This method is typically more efficient and 'controllable' than using (say) a variable resistor to vary the voltage in order to change the speed of the blower.  See this for more info https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/pulse-width-modulation.html

EDIT: The above aside, as per the other answers/comments your photos do suggest you're setup to measure current not voltage(!).... if the current is flowing through the meter, the motor will still work.